# jvisualvm profiler version error

Tags: java, wildfly, profiler, jvisualvm

I'm trying to profile some wildfly based application. CPU and memory sampling is working fine, but not profiling. After clicking Profiler -> Memory I get:

"Warning: The profiler agent you are connecting to is a different version than this profiler. You may encounter errors and unexpected behavior"

And then:

"Unexpected problem when trying to start target application: Target VM terminated or does not respond"

Visual VM version 1.3.8 and java version "1.8.0_20" on Windows 7 64-bit

Comment: If you use Wildfly **10** , VisualVM does not support it at any hand([JDK-8145964](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8145964)). You can use NetBeans Profiler alternatively.

Comment: Yes it's v10. Tried remote but it fails because of  java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYCTL0079: Failed initializing module org.jboss.as.logging
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31401924/arquillian-wildfly8-2-embedded-jbas014670-failed-initializing-module-org-jbos

Comment: Looks like there is no easy way to start wildfly with agent. What a pain...